# Flutter Google Maps, Marker Dragging

Tags: google-maps, flutter, drag, gesturedetector

If anyone could help with this I would be very grateful.

So my problem is making a Marker drag without a delay in Flutter google_maps plugin. I have tried the standard way of making the marker move by setting the marker draggable property to true which is fine and it does work, but to initiate the drag you have to hold your finger down on the marker for a while in other words it is not an instant drag.  I know this is the standard behavior for Google Maps but is there a way around this?

I would like it if it was more instant like this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.noframe.fieldsareameasure&hl=en_GB (Dragging starts on editing an area)

Another solution I have tried is to add an image over the top of the map and attach a GestureDetector to it and then use the getLatLng function from the google_maps plugin to the LatLng position from the X, Y coordinates given by the GestureDectector. But the LatLng does not match up to the Image location when typed into Google Maps.

```
 dragMarker(double x, double y) async {
      ScreenCoordinate screenCoordinate = ScreenCoordinate(x: x.toInt(), y: y.toInt());
      LatLng pos = await googleMapController.getLatLng(screenCoordinate);
      print("X: " + (x.toInt() + 26).toString() + " Y: " + y.toInt().toString());
      print(pos.latitude.toString() + " : " +  pos.longitude.toString());
  }
```

Any thoughts?